# Resizing split panes in vim with {n}Ctrl-W +/- not working as described on MacOS

Tags: split, macos

I am using vim on MacOS.

I have one vertical split down the middle and two panes split horizontally on the left side ( `:Vex` <kbd>Ctrl w</kbd>`h` `:Sex` ).

From my understanding *n*<kbd>Ctrl w</kbd> `+|-` should resize the focused pane vertically by *n* lines ; or if you exclude the *n* , one line at a time. However, when I run this command in either of the panes on the left, the pane only gets resized as specified only once , but the second time I run the command, the pane either maximizes or minimizes.

The other thing I'm noticing is the panes don't resize beyond the halfway mark other than fully maximizing or minimizing.

If anyone knows what is causing this behaviour whether by my ignorance or the program, please chime in. Thank you!

Comment: Does it happen with `$ vim -Nu NONE` or `$ vim --clean`?

Comment: what keys exactly did you press?

Comment: Looks like OP is forgetting to press `<Shift>`.

Comment: You should check your settings [[ `winheight` & `winminheight` & etc ]] to get clues about what is going wrong where !

Answer (score 0):

I did you scenario here, and it seems to work fine

[image: reproducing the problem]

To maximize panes in Vim

- vertically, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>-</kbd>
- horizontally, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd>

Note that wile increasing with <kbd>+</kbd>, if you omit the <kbd>Shift</kbd> you end up with `:h CTRL-W_=`

Hope this helps